# WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot determine loading status from unknown error: missing or invalid columnNumber

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, error-handling

I wrote a code in python to scrape this website: https://www.fragrantica.com/search/

My problem is that while looping to get me the links of all of the perfumes available it would throw this error:

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot determine loading status from unknown error: 
missing or invalid columnNumber
```

it would just throw it randomly throughout the code and I can never pinpoint the location since it happens at different lines and at different stages.
I already tried the option of using incognito, and also upgrading my webdriver to 104 and also using the new chrome beta version 104 and still same problem.

how can i approach this and fix it ??